# I don't see my buttons when running the simulator - Xcode10

Tags: ios, xcode

I was trying to follow a tutorial online but the version that was being used was older than the most recent Xcode10.
I have added a navigation controller and added buttons to the controller... 
[navigation controller with buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y6cb.png)

But when I run the simulator, I do not see the 2 buttons that I created....[simulator without buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWOWR.png)

Any ideas why this would be the case? All help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the height, `UITableViewCell` rely on the content of the cell and to be able to do that you should add constraints to the buttons you have already added.

[image]

or you should implement the delegate method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
         heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I could not find that "Add Constraints" feature in XCode 10. Is this the same version you are using?

Comment: When I insert a button directly into the Table View, I can see the button when running the app...but when I try to add another button, it won't populate into the editor. If you know of any good tutorials for Xcode 10, send them my way :) I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @ShilohJordan I guess you should learn autolayout first, here is a good tutorial that you should look at: https://www.raywenderlich.com/443-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started